# Adding HTTPS in Local wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, https

I have install wordpress locally which is deployed on apache on port 8888.
so my website url looks like http://www.localhost:8888/wordpress/*

How can i make this secure ?

Answer (score 0):

Does changing `siteurl` and `home` in the options table of the database to include "https" not work for you?